# I'm getting the error: "Type doesn't conform to protocol 'Comparable'" when trying to compile a Swift code from manual

Tags: swift

I tried the example below from [the Swift - Protocols manual page](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html), but I am getting the compiler error:

`error: type 'SkillLevel' does not conform to protocol 'Comparable'`:

```swift
enum SkillLevel: Comparable {
    case beginner
    case intermediate
    case expert(stars: Int)
}
var levels = [SkillLevel.intermediate, SkillLevel.beginner,
              SkillLevel.expert(stars: 5), SkillLevel.expert(stars: 3)]
for level in levels.sorted() {
    print(level)
}
```

Xcode suggests to add the function below to make it to conform to Comparable:

```swift
static func < (lhs: SkillLevel, rhs: SkillLevel) -> Bool {
    <#code#>
}
```

From the manual:

> Swift provides a synthesized implementation of Comparable for enumerations that don’t have a raw value. If the enumeration has associated types, they must all conform to the Comparable protocol. To receive a synthesized implementation of <, declare conformance to Comparable in the file that contains the original enumeration declaration, without implementing a < operator yourself. The Comparable protocol’s default implementation of <=, >, and >= provides the remaining comparison operators.

I'm not sure if the enumeration in the code above has a raw value, but if it doesn't, shouldn't the code had compiled without the implementation of the function "<"?

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? This was only recently introduced in Swift 5.3.

Comment: You code compiles fine for me with Xcode 12 beta

Comment: Yep no sign of this in the 5.2 doc

Comment: I'm using Swift 5.2.4. I wasn't aware the docs were updated for 5.3. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I (OP) was using an older Swift version, and the manual applies to the newest version.

Answer (score -2):

Automatically generating the < operator works if you have something similar to a plain C enum; just the cases and nothing else. But here one of the cases has an associated type, so the compiler doesn't want to guess how you want values ordered.

Comment: Yet, the linked documentation suggests otherwise... I'm surprised that this example is part of the swift documentation. Edit: Oh wait, is this a 5.3 thing?